# Increase the height of the triangle html

Tags: html, pointers, text-size

I want to use this triangle pointer in the font section of my menus.
The code is the html triangle pointer is: `&#x25C2;` (◂)

Using text size tags, I can change the size of the text, but I do not want to spray it and only increase its height.
what's the solution?

Comment: _spray_ ? You mean increase the width (spread?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform`. The following CSS would double the character's height without changing it's width.

```
transform: scaleY(2);
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem with your solution have solved.

Answer (score 0):

try to add span inside your menus.

```
<span class="pointer"></span>
```

and add css like

```
    .pointer{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7.5px 5px 7.5px 0;
    border-color: transparent #000000 transparent transparent;}
```